# XPath выбрать текст без одного дочернего элемента

Tags: xpath, xslt

есть хмл

```
<x>
  <y>Текст не нужун</y>
  <z>текст1</z>
  текст2
  <z>текст3</z>
</x>
```

нужно получить текствое значение элемента x, без поделемента y.

текст1 
текст2 
текст3

пробую как то так, не получается:
    string(x/self::node()[not(y)])

Правка: выборка проходит в xslt. Если кому-то захочется помочь вот заготовка:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="x"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="x">
  <out_text>
    <!-- <xsl:value-of select="*[name() != 'y']"/> -->
    <!-- <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant-or-self::*[name()!= 'y']" mode="my_concat"   />  -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant-or-self::*[name()!= 'y']" mode="my_concat"   /> 
  </out_text>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="*[name()!= 'y']" mode="my_concat" >
  <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Попробуйте так `/x/*[name() != 'y']/text() | /x/text()[position() = 2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На одном из других форумов подсказали и работает:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/x/descendant-or-self::*[not(self::y)]/text()"/>
```

Comment: Пометьте, пожалуйста, как ответ (галочка слева от ответа), чтобы помочь кому-то в будующем)

Answer (score 0):

```
/x/*[name() != 'y']
```

Вроде вот так должно получиться (проверял тут http://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester)

Comment: Нет, не попомгло, не работает как надо. Отсеиваится "текст 2" Немного уточню, выбираю элементы в xslt, затем пробую их "сцепить" через такой темплейт: <xsl:template match="*" mode="my_concat" >
    <xsl:for-each select="descendant::*">
      <xsl:value-of select="./text()"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>